# resolving instance of class inside of method using autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

Using this PipelineX class below, is there any way to resolve the filters applied to the pipline without injecting the autofac container and calling _container.Resolve();

```
 public class PipelineX<T> : FilterBase<T>, IPipelineX<T>
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public PipelineX(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }
    protected override T Process(T input)
    {
        return input;
    }

    public PipelineX<T> FilterBy<X>()
    {
        var filter = _container.Resolve(typeof(X)) as IFilter<T>;
        Register(filter);
        return this;
    }                             
}
```

Comment: You can inject IEnumerable<IFilter<T>> into constructor. https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html

Comment: Instead of passing the container to the `PipelineX` class, you can pass a factory object that is responsible for creating/resolving the instances of `IFilter<T>`

Comment: Let's say there are 100 types that implement `IFilter<T>`. The OPs current code will instantiate only one of them. I suspect your code @MuratTüfekçi will instantiate all 100 of them. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: How does you current registration of IFilter to autofac look?

Comment: builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(PipelineX<>)).As(typeof(IPipelineX<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<PersonRecordTrimFieldsFilter>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

Comment: This is commonly known as the [service locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/), instead, you should figure out what to pass into the constructor of the class to inject the proper factory or provider for this kind of service. Some service containers can even register open generics, in which case you might even be able to just take a dependency (in the constructor) on `IFilter<T>`. I don't know AutoFac, however, so I don't know how or if you can do that.

Comment: You also state "filters applied to the pipeline", where "filters" is written in plural state, meaning multiple filters, is that what you want, or will there only ever be one filter for one `<T>` ?

Comment: However, now I see that you depend on a parameter to the method to get your filters. You will probably need to wrap the handling of this in a factory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid the usage of Autofac as a service locator you can register your own factory method into it, in this case:

```
builder.Register<Func<Type, object>>((c, p) =>
{
    var context = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
    return type => context.Resolve(type);
});
```

and use that in your `PipelineX` class like this:

```
private readonly Func<Type, object> filterFactory;

public PipelineX(Func<Type, object> filterFactory)
{
    this.filterFactory = filterFactory;
}

protected override T Process(T input)
{
    return input;
}

public PipelineX<T> FilterBy<X>()
{
    var filter = this.filterFactory(typeof(X)) as IFilter<T>;
    Register(filter);
    return this;
}
```

**Consider:** This only removes the hard reference to the Autofac container, it's still using an abstract object factory which is not self explanatory enough and should be replaced by a custom filter factory or selector implementation.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to Péter's answer but uses a custom factory:

```
public class FilterFactory
{
    private readonly Func<Type, object> _factoryFunc;

    public FilterFactory(Func<Type, object> factoryFunc)
    {
        _factoryFunc = factoryFunc ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(factoryFunc));
    }

    public IFilter<T> Create<X, T>() 
    {
        IFilter<T> filter = Create<T>(typeof(X));

        return filter;
    }

    public IFilter<T> Create<T>(Type type) 
    {
        var filter = _factoryFunc(type) as IFilter<T>;

        if (filter == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Could not find filter for type '{type.FullName}'");
        }

        return filter;
    }
}
```

PipelineX implementation would be:

```
public class PipelineX<T> : FilterBase<T>, IPipelineX<T>
{
    private readonly FilterFactory _factory;

    public PipelineX(FilterFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    protected override T Process(T input)
    {
        return input;
    }

    public PipelineX<T> FilterBy<X>()
    {
        var filter = _factory.Create<X,T>() as IFilter<T>;
        Register(filter);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Registering the factory using Autofac:

```
builder.Register<FilterFactory>(c =>
{
    var context = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
    return new FilterFactory(context.Resolve);
});
```