# C# MVC5 AutoFac IoC - Resolve based on requesting class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm trying to configure Autofac in a MVC5 project to return a specific implementation of an interface, based on the class that's requesting it.

This is something I have done a lot with PHP using the Laravel framework, which offers a solution like the below:

```
$this->app->when(PhotoController::class)
          ->needs(Filesystem::class)
          ->give(function () {
              return Storage::disk('local');
          });
```

So far my Googling has come up short, with most answers suggesting I inject either a Factory (Calling the Container), or the Container it's self, and pull the Service I need from there.

Is there really no way to achieve something similar to the above?

Comment: I'm not sure what "_when.... needs_" means. Also, is FileSystem supposed to be an interface or base class? You can: 1) create a PhotoController class that takes a Filesystem as a parameter, or 2) create a PhotoController class that takes a factory as a parameter, or 3) create a PhotoController class that takes a delegate as a parameter. The factory or the delegate would be responsible to create the instance of Filesystem in runtime, if/when needed.

Comment: Hi Jarimba, yes Filesystem would be an interface in the above example, generally the I prefix isn't used in PHP, but it'd be clear in the IDE. In essence it's exactly as it reads in English, when class A needs interface A, give it class B. It's the logic of being able to resolve the interface based on the requestor that I'm interested in. It's proofed extremely useful in PHP.

Comment: Have you [read this related FAQ](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)?

Comment: @TravisIllig I had, but hadn't realized what it was doing in the context of the example, Peter Casjtai's answer below helper clear it up. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are options to register conditional dependencies, the easiest with Autofac is the named registration (AFAIK):

```
builder.Register(c => new DiskStorage()).Named<IStorage>("disk");
builder.Register(c => new PhotoController(c.ResolveNamed<IStorage>("disk")));
```

Comment: This would work but I have the impression the OP needs something more _dynamic_, given his/her comment: `inject inject either a Factory (...) or the Container itself, and pull the Service I need from there`. He might need to use a [factory method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52991060/558486) ;-)

Comment: Thanks @péter-csajtai, this looks promising, however do you know if I'm able to call `new DiskStorage()` without having to manually build it's dependencies? Currently I'm having to do `builder.Register(c => new DiskStorage(new DependencyA(new DependencyB()))).Named<IStorage>("disk");`

Comment: You can let the Container resolve those top level dependencies of the storage like: `new DiskStorage(c.Resolve<DependencyA>())`